# Apex Auto-Follow in Chatter

Tags: apex, chatter, follow

I need to develop Apex code to allow team members to auto-follow in Chatter when they are added to the Account.  Team members are added to fields, and our consultant developed code to push the field information to the Account Team.  I want to use the field inputs, instead of the Account Team, to build out our auto-follow team.  I recently took the DEV 501 course, and included in the course is a great guideline for auto-follow.  I'm trying to adapt that code for our purposes, but am not experienced enough to get around my issue.

Managing_Director_lu__c, Underwriting_Director__c, and Claims_Manager_lu__c are all custom lookup fields to the User object.  All three fields will be populated, and all three team members will need to auto-follow simultaneously.

Apex Class:

```
public class AutoFollowOrgs {

    public static void OrgTeamSubscribeOrg(List <Account> accts) {
        System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: Entering');

        List<EntitySubscription> subscriptions = new List <EntitySubscription>();
        for (Account acct: accts) {
            EntitySubscription eSubs = new EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id);
            if(acct.Managing_Director_lu__c != NULL){
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Managing_Director_lu__c;
            }
            subscriptions.add(eSubs);
            if(acct.Underwriting_Director__c != NULL){
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Underwriting_Director__c;
            }
            subscriptions.add(eSubs);
            if(acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c != NULL){
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c;
            }
            subscriptions.add(eSubs);
        }
        try {
            Database.insert(subscriptions);
        }
        catch (DMLException dmlEx) {
            //if we get an error because this user is already following this object, it's okay.
            if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0) == statusCode.DUPLICATE_VALUE) {
                System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: subscription already exists');
            } else {
                //otherwise we have a more serious error that we need to throw.
                throw dmlEx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the issue lies with my subscriptions.add(eSubs) code.  If I place it at the end of all the IF statements, only the last team member is added.  This makes sense because I realized I was basically replacing the ParentID and SubscriberId with each IF statement.  So, I tried adding the line after each IF statement, and get the following error when I run the code:

> Error:Apex trigger AutoFollowOrgsTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: AutoFollowOrgsTrigger:
>   execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: Before
>   Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements:
>   Class.AutoFollowOrgs.OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: line 28, column 1

Okay, I guess this also makes sense because I must still only adding data to one line in the list, not multiple lines.

How do I adapt my code so that each team member is a different row in the list?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing a list will solve your issue:

```
public class AutoFollowOrgs {

    public static void OrgTeamSubscribeOrg(List <Account> accts) {
        System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: Entering');

        List<EntitySubscription> subscriptions = new List <EntitySubscription>();
        for (Account acct: accts) {
            if(acct.Managing_Director_lu__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id,SubscriberId = acct.Managing_Director_lu__c));
            }
            if(acct.Underwriting_Director__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id,SubscriberId = Underwriting_Director__c));
            }
            if(acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id,SubscriberId = Claims_Manager_lu__c));
            }
        }
        try {
            Database.insert(subscriptions);
        }
        catch (DMLException dmlEx) {
            //if we get an error because this user is already following this object, it's okay.
            if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0) == statusCode.DUPLICATE_VALUE) {
                System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: subscription already exists');
            } else {
                //otherwise we have a more serious error that we need to throw.
                throw dmlEx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution, Eric, but there's a minor error - you're not adding eSubs to subscriptions.  I suggest adding directly to subscriptions instead, since the eSubs list is effectively redundant.

Comment: @SpongeBob - Thanks for that, did not see the other list  - Updated answer

Comment: Oh, that works brilliantly!  Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a subscription for each of those custom fields on the account.  So something like this:

```
public class AutoFollowOrgs {

    public static void OrgTeamSubscribeOrg(List <Account> accts) {
        System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: Entering');

        List<EntitySubscription> subscriptions = new List <EntitySubscription>();
        for (Account acct: accts) {

            if(acct.Managing_Director_lu__c != NULL){
                EntitySubscription eSubs = new EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id);
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Managing_Director_lu__c;
                subscriptions.add(eSubs);
            }

            if(acct.Underwriting_Director__c != NULL){
                EntitySubscription eSubs = new EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id);
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Underwriting_Director__c;
                subscriptions.add(eSubs);
            }

            if(acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c != NULL){
                EntitySubscription eSubs = new EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id);
                eSubs.SubscriberId = acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c;
                subscriptions.add(eSubs);
            }

        }
        try {
            Database.insert(subscriptions);
        }
        catch (DMLException dmlEx) {
            //if we get an error because this user is already following this object, it's okay.
            if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0) == statusCode.DUPLICATE_VALUE) {
                System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: subscription already exists');
            } else {
                //otherwise we have a more serious error that we need to throw.
                throw dmlEx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```