# Apex Test Class for Chatter Auto-Follow

Tags: apex, unit-test

I had some great help with getting my Class to work properly ([Apex Auto-Follow in Chatter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83219/apex-auto-follow-in-chatter)).  Now I'm writing my first Test Method, and running into an error I can't seem to work around.

Apex Class:

```
public class AutoFollowOrgs {

    public static void OrgTeamSubscribeOrg(List <Account> accts) {
        System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: Entering');

        List<EntitySubscription> subscriptions = new List <EntitySubscription>();
        for (Account acct: accts) {
            if(acct.Managing_Director_lu__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Managing_Director_lu__c));
            }
            if(acct.Underwriting_Director__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Underwriting_Director__c));
            }
            if(acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Claims_Manager_lu__c));
            }
            if(acct.Actuary__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Actuary__c));
            }
            if(acct.Risk_Manager_lu__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Risk_Manager_lu__c));
            }
            if(acct.Client_Analytics_Manager__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Client_Analytics_Manager__c));
            }
            if(acct.Brand_Manager__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Brand_Manager__c));
            }
            if(acct.Supporting_Managing_Director__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Supporting_Managing_Director__c));
            }
            if(acct.Supporting_MD_2__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Supporting_MD_2__c));
            }
            if(acct.Supporting_MD_3__c != NULL){
                subscriptions.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId = acct.Id, SubscriberId = acct.Supporting_MD_3__c));
            }
        }
        try {
            Database.insert(subscriptions);
        }
        catch (DMLException dmlEx) {
            //if we get an error because this user is already following this object, it's okay.
            if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0) == statusCode.DUPLICATE_VALUE) {
                System.Debug('OrgTeamSubscribeOrg: subscription already exists');
            } else {
                //otherwise we have a more serious error that we need to throw.
                throw dmlEx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
//Test the AutoFollowOrgs Class and Trigger -- mh 07/13/15
private class AutoFollowOrgsTest {

    //Verify that user auto-follows when added to Organization Team
    static testmethod void AutoFollowOrgs_Test(){

        //Load test Profile
        Map<String, Profile> profiles = new Map<String, Profile>();
        for(Profile p : [select id, name from profile where name IN ('System Administrator')]){
            profiles.put(p.Name, p);
        }

        //Load test Users
        User u1 = new User(alias = 'test01', email='test01@testorg.com',
                        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = profiles.get('System Administrator').Id,
                        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test01@testorg.com');
        User u2 = new User(alias = 'test02', email='test02@testorg.com',
                        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = profiles.get('System Administrator').Id,
                        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test02@testorg.com');
        User u3 = new User(alias = 'test03', email='test03@testorg.com',
                        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = profiles.get('System Administrator').Id,
                        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test03@testorg.com');

        //Load test Account 
        Account acc1 = new Account(Name='Test01', Managing_Director_lu__c = u1.Id, Claims_Manager_lu__c = u2.Id, Actuary__c = u3.Id);
        insert new List<Account>{acc1};

       //Load test Chatter subscriptions                  
        EntitySubscription eSub1 = new EntitySubscription(ParentID = acc1.Id, SubscriberId = acc1.Managing_Director_lu__c);
        EntitySubscription eSub2 = new EntitySubscription(ParentID = acc1.Id, SubscriberId = acc1.Claims_Manager_lu__c);
        EntitySubscription eSub3 = new EntitySubscription(ParentID = acc1.Id, SubscriberId = acc1.Actuary__c);
        insert new List<EntitySubscription>{eSub1, eSub2, eSub3};

        Map<Id, EntitySubscription> eSubs2Check = new Map<Id, EntitySubscription>([SELECT Id, ParentId, SubscriberId FROM EntitySubscription WHERE Id IN :new List<EntitySubscription>{eSub1, eSub2, eSub3}]);
        System.assertEquals(eSub1.SubscriberId, eSubs2Check.get(eSub1.Id).SubscriberId);
        System.assertEquals(eSub2.SubscriberId, eSubs2Check.get(eSub2.Id).SubscriberId);
        System.assertEquals(eSub3.SubscriberId, eSubs2Check.get(eSub3.Id).SubscriberId);    
    }   
}
```

I can get the test method to pass until until I try to insert the Chatter subscription test data in line 36 (insert new List{eSub1, eSub2, eSub3};).

I keep getting the error message:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

My research on this error indicates that my lookup field is filling in the wrong record ID.  That confuses me because I think I'm loading the same data as my Class, only with test data.  I've tried loading the SubscriberID as both u1.Id and acc1.Managing_Director_lu__c and get the same result.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presently not inserting the `User` objects so their ID values will be null.

Add:

```
insert new User[] {u1, u2, u3};
```

immediately after you initialise the `User` objects.

Comment: Thank you Keith.  I've added that line, but now I'm getting a different error on that same line.  _'System.DmlException: Insert failed.  First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>:[]'_  I've tried adding an additional two accounts, but continue to get the same error.  I also tried an UPSERT instead of INSERT with the same result.

Comment: @italiahall If your class is run from an Account trigger then it will have already inserted the subscriptions by the time your test inserts them. I don't understand why your test is inserting them: I would have expected your test to query them to confirm that the trigger added them.

Comment: Thank you again Keith.  I restructured my code, and now have 96% code coverage.